# Dispatchers.IO or Dispatchers.Main in official coroutines guide

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In the Android official coroutines guides [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv), there are two code examples. In the first example, a function get(url: String) called from fetchDocs() runs on Dispatchers.IO, but in the second example it runs on Dispatchers.Main - see a second comment in each example.
Is it an error, or they actually run on different Dispatchers?

First example

```
suspend fun fetchDocs() {                             // Dispatchers.Main
    val result = get("https://developer.android.com") // Dispatchers.IO for `get`
    show(result)                                      // Dispatchers.Main
}

suspend fun get(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /* ... */ }
```

Second example

```
suspend fun fetchDocs() {                      // Dispatchers.Main
    val result = get("developer.android.com")  // Dispatchers.Main
    show(result)                               // Dispatchers.Main
}

suspend fun get(url: String) =                 // Dispatchers.Main
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {              // Dispatchers.IO (main-safety block)
        /* perform network IO here */          // Dispatchers.IO (main-safety block)
    }                                          // Dispatchers.Main
}
```

Comment: The two examples appear to be identical, except for whitespace and the missing `https://` in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the intention of the author of this article was to make the first example simplified to show that we can easily switch between threads line after line. In both examples `get()` is executed using `Dispatchers.Main`, but it immediately jumps to `Dispatchers.IO`, so it was marked as `IO` for simplicity. The documentation even mentions that:

> In this example, get() still runs on the main thread (...)

Anyway, I agree this may be confusing for the reader.

Comment: That was my understanding, but I wasn't 100% sure - get() function runs on the main thread until it enters withContext(Dispatchers.IO), where it suspends, and then resumes after getting the result from the withContext block. Since fetchDocs() doesn't care about Dispatcher and runs on the main thread, they should use // Dispatchers.Main in both examples I think.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is 100% correct.